# Full Orientation of the Andromeda and Triangulum Galaxies

Tags: galaxy

I can find the degree of inclination compared to Earth for both the Andromeda and Triangulum Galaxies wherever I search. For instance, the Triangulum Galaxy has an inclination of 54 degrees compared to Earth. However, objects in 3 dimensions require two angles to fully describe their orientation, so there is still one more degree of freedom to account for with these galaxies.

What would the full orientation for both of these galaxies be relative to our galactic plane?

Comment: You might get what you want from the OpenNGC catalog.  It has the ellipticity and position angle. https://github.com/mattiaverga/OpenNGC

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you :)